# I am a symbol of love, or hate, peace or war - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> When someone loves their country like I do,
>
> they rise up.
>
> When the world buffet, I get moving.
>
> I am a symbol of love, or hate,
>
> peace or war.
>
> So whatever happens, just wave.

What am I?

Comment: Ohhhhh, it's buf-fet, not buf-fay. That makes so much more sense!

Comment: Why not "When the world buffets"?

Comment: @PeregrineRook, to confuse people and make it more challenging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are:

> a Flag

When someone loves their country like I do, they raise up

> Flags are used to represent a country and used to show national pride by raising a flag.

When the world buffet, I get moving.

> Flags wave when it's windy

I am a symbol of love, or hate, peace or war.

> Flags can be used to represent support for different beliefs

So whatever happens, just wave.

> Flags wave

Comment: ----- Well done!